# Why Fibonacci recursive algorithm working too slow ?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am using recursive algorithm to generate fibonacci numbers using java.
The algorithm is taking too much of time to give simple addition of 2 numbers (crossing 10 digits) than a human. windows calculator can perform even the powers of big numbers (Ex: 7^1000) in fraction of seconds. Both windows calculator and my Fibonacci algorithm works on same windows i5 processor.

why my Fibonacci algorithm is taking too much time for simple addition ?

Comment: Since our crystal ball is broken, would you care showing us some of your code?

Comment: Because every recursion goes down two paths? Monitor the number of function calls to your recursive function and you'll soon see why.

Comment: The addition is not the time consuming part of a classical recursive version of fibonacci. It's the fact that `fib(10)` adds two numbers together 177 times to compute `55`. It grows exponentially so that `fib(20)` adds numbers  together 21891 times. fib(30) does 2 million additions to compute 832040.

Comment: afaik, there is no such thing as a windows processor.

Comment: Recursion is a poor solution for calculating Fibonacci because it doesn't save the previous value. Dynamic programming is a much faster solution, which just means save the previous value you calculated so you can use it in the next calculation.

Comment: @JosephJames If there is a chance you will use the same function twice then a recursive solution with memoization will win against an iterative solution that always does `O(n)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic recursive implementation of `fib` is this:

```c
int fib(int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return n;
    else
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

This function recurses so many times, it is used as an easy benchmark to measure function call efficiency in various languages, with a time complexity of **O(φ<sup>n</sup>)**.

You want an iterative implementation that will perform like a charm:

```c
int fib(int n) {
    int a = 0, b = 1, c = n;
    while (n --> 1) {  // (n --> 1) is parsed as (n-- > 1)
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially and normally a computer can iterate around 10^8 - 10^9 values of n in one seconds.If you will execute a recursive function, may be the function is taking lots of values because of which the program is executing slowly.

Also, the runtime doesn't only depends on the processor, there's various other factors to(such as RAM, programming language, Memory etc.).To check the runtime of programs various concept such as Big-Oh Notations are used.